# Reference a User that was created with the default Membership Provider within ASP.NET MVC3 in a table located in another database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

To reference a foreign key in a table I use the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ExampleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Example Example { get; set; }
}
```

How would I reference a User within the default Membership Provider that is used within ASP.NET's MVC 3 ?

I would think it would be something as simple as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

. . . but I do not know how to specifically reference a User (There is not a "User" class, I know there are classes for LogOnModel and RegisterModel - but these do not directly reference the User itself).

**How would I accomplish this relationship within my table?**

Am I approaching the situation in a way that is considered unconventional?

(To be clear: I am wanting to make a relationship between the User that was created using the default Membership Provider and a table in my own database)

Comment: You can't access tables in another database from Entity Framework.  It's not suppoted

Comment: Good to know, I'll use a different work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  First, in order to do that you would need to map the user tables into  your data model.  Doing that, however, is not recommended because you then have two different systems managing the same data.

Instead, you would do something like this:

```
from d in dc.MyClasses where d.UserID == Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey select d
```

In order to find out which user is associated with your data.  You need to add a uniqueidentifier column to your class, then when you create the MyClass you add the users ProviderUserKey.  Then, when you get the MyClass, you lookup the user by the key via the Membership API.

EDIT:

I didn't notice the part where you said a different database.  As I said in my comment, Entity Framework does not support mapping tables in other databases.  It's single-database only.  It's possible to create views that map to another database, and then map those views into yours, but you have to manage all relationships manually, and it's going to be read-only.

The easiest way to access the membership data in another database is to point the membership data provider to that database (membership api providers have different connection strings than your EF databawse) and then use the techniques I mention above.

Comment: As a followup, I've discovered that it's relatively easy to use a feature in SQL 2005+ called "Synonyms" to map tables from other databases into your data model.  However, this really only works well in Code-First.  Database and Model first won't understand synonyms.